# How to handle the close (big X) button at the source?

Tags: .net, winforms

We would like under some circumstances to block the action of the close button in the title bar. The problem is that it's a MDI applications and it seems that we will have to add code in each forms to cancel the operation in the `Closing`event handler. It seems that the child forms are the first to receive the event. There is no way to add code at a single place to cancel the close operation. Information on how the close event is propagated to the child form would be welcome. Is there a simple way of doing what we want to do?

Comment: You could subclass Form, write the code for Closing in it, then use that instead of Form for your children.

Comment: @Michael. The difficulty is that it's a legacy application and there is many Forms already implemented. Changing the class inherited isn't too hard. The problem is that each of those class have handlers on the `Closing`event. I could bind them to another custom event called from the inherited class. I'm still hoping for a better solution but that's the best I got so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows provides a way to do this, you can tinker with the system menu.  Provides for nice feedback as well, the close button will actually look disabled.  You can disable the SC_CLOSE command in the system menu.  Best demonstrated with a sample form, get started by dropping a button on it:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...

public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
    }

    private bool mCloseEnabled = true;
    public bool CloseEnabled {
        get { return mCloseEnabled; }
        set {
            if (value == mCloseEnabled) return;
            mCloseEnabled = value;
            setSystemMenu();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        setSystemMenu();
    }
    private void setSystemMenu() {
        IntPtr menu = GetSystemMenu(this.Handle, false);
        EnableMenuItem(menu, SC_CLOSE, mCloseEnabled ? 0 : 1);
    }
    private const int SC_CLOSE = 0xf060;
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool revert);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int EnableMenuItem(IntPtr hMenu, int IDEnableItem, int wEnable);

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        CloseEnabled = !CloseEnabled;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Michael already wrote the answer in the comments (just to add it here to the answers):

Create a single BaseFormsClass where you override the behaviour and then subclass your classes from the new BaseFormsClass.

Comment: You could try to intercept WM_CLOSE window messages. But unless you literally have thousands of existing forms I think the base-class approach will be the easiest/fastest one.